# Need to write a trigger

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I need to write a trigger on Event object. 
condition : if the difference between 2 fields (both are date time fields) is more than 7days then the trigger should fire and update else not.

eg: the field 1. start data, 2. end date

start date = 06/05/2012 
end date = 13/05/2012

then the trigger should fire. 
can anybody please tell me how to compare date in Apex-code.

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [daysBetween()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm).

```
date startDate = date.newInstance(2008, 1, 1);
date dueDate = date.newInstance(2008, 1, 30);
integer numberDaysDue = startDate.daysBetween(dueDate);
```